# where is the button widget in pyglet ?

Tags: python, pyglet

i'm checking out pyglet, but, funny enough, i can't find how to do a simple button!

so

- **what is the standard way to create a standard button?**
- is there a standard way to create a Message-Box? open/save dialogs?
- or am i missing the point of pyglet? isn't it yet-another gui toolkit
  for creating (also) forms, windows, buttons, texts, standard widgets, etc. ?

i'm using Python 2.x on a windows PC if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't use Pyglet yet, but is not a GUI library, it doesn't have to have widgets like buttons, or containers etc. It's a multimedia library like Pygame, it draws stuff on screen, plays sounds, and has some helper functions.

If you want to draw a button on screen, you should first draw a rectangle, print some text in it, and then listen mouse clicks to know if it's clicked on this rectangle.

See PyQT, PyGTK, WxPython for some examples of GUI libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can see an example of how to create a button and create yet another interface with Pyglet in the script:

http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/media_player.py

But this is only an example interface created without complex items.

Comment: The link is dead (404 — Page Not Found)

Comment: @Marv yes, and I will note that more 5 years since that answer. Right now you may see source on GitHub by address https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/blob/master/examples/media_player.py#L97

Answer (score 1):

Current state of affairs 3 years later...

As previously stated Pyglet itself generally provides a lower level api than the UI widget library (e.g. closer to GDI or SDL).

That said there are gui's built on top of pyglet:
    https://github.com/jorgecarleitao/pyglet-gui
    https://code.google.com/p/kytten/

Also pyglet 1.2 now has buttons itself (though not much else as far as widgets are concerned).